# patch function in a different module imported by module under test

Tags: python-3.x, mocking

EDIT 1: Added extra functions missed the first time

Here's the basic setup:

---- module path.to.base.module.db: ----

```
def init_url(...):
    <checks on opts>
    db_url = 'sqlite:///path/to/sqlite/file.sql'
    return db_url

def init_db(url, base=None):
    engine = <sqlalchemy create engine with url>
    session = <sqlalchemy create session>
    base.create_all(engine)
    return session

class Manager():
    def __init__(...):
        self.db_url = init_url(...)
        self.session = init_db(self.db_url)
```

---- module path.to.my.module.db: ----

```
from path.to.base.module.db import Manager

class Projector():
   <sqlalchemy declarative table defines>

class ProjectorDB(Manager):
    super(Projector, self).__init__(...)

    def add_record(....):
        <basic checks and add record>
        if added:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

---- nose test module: ----

```
from path.to.my.module.db import Projector

class test_my_db_module:
    def setUp():
        self.mocked_init_url = patch('path.to.base.module.init_url')
        self.mocked_init_url.start()
        self.mocked_init_url.return_value = 'sqlite://'
        self.projector = ProjectorDB()

    def tearDown():
        self.mocked_init_url.stop()

    def test_add_record(self):
        added = self.projector.add_record(....)
```

The problem is that when I run the test_add_record, I get this error:

'projector has no method "add_record()"

So I changed the test:

```
class test_my_db_module:
    def setUp():
        self.mocked_init_url = patch('path.to.base.module.init_url')
        self.mocked_init_url.start()
        self.mocked_init_url.return_value = 'sqlite://'

    def tearDown():
        self.mocked_init_url.stop()

    def test_add_record(self):
        projector = ProjectorDB()
        added = projector.add_record(....)
```

Now I get:
  sqalchemy: no such table 'Projector'

When I checked the log output, projector = Projector() apparently created the in-memory db, but the sql file was still created and that's what was used - which at this time did not have the tables defined. The log entry showed:

Manager.self.db_url = 'sqlite://path/to/sqlite/file.sql

rather than:

Manager.self.db_url = 'sqlite://'

At what point am I not understanding patching?

Comment: Your patched path appears to be incorrect: `'path.to.base.module.init_url'` but your `init_url` is at `'path.to.base.module.db.init_url'`.

Comment: Found the issue, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, SQLAlchemy tables when using declarative do not like to use memory db.

The solution was to change from using a memory db to using a temp file for the db.

```
tmpfile = '/tmp/test-projectordb.sql'

class TestProjectorDB(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        if not hasattr(self, 'projector'):
            with patch('path.to.my.module.projectordb.init_url') as mocked_init_url:
                mocked_init_url.start()
                mocked_init_url.return_value = 'sqlite:///%s' % tmpfile
                self.projector = ProjectorDB()
```